# The report has no tables. Crystal Report C# Error

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have applied everything but could not find any way out. following is my code in which i am filling the dataset table with name and still my ReportDocument gives me a error The report has no tables.

```
MySqlCommand command = null;  
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = null;  
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();  
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();  
try  
 {  
  if (connection == null) { connection = MYSQLConnect.getInstance().getDBConnection(); }  
command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);  
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);  
connection.Open();  
dataTable.TableName = "REPORTDATA";  
dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);  
adapter.Fill(dataSet, "REPORTDATA");  
document.SetDataSource(dataSet.Tables["REPORTDATA"]);  
}  
catch (Exception e)
```